# As a Canadian, what should I invest in if I'm betting that the Canadian real estate will crash?

Tags: canada, real-estate, investing

I apologize in advance if this question seems unethical as you may think I'm trying to profit from people's losses. I'm just trying to protect my investments.

So here's my question: if I'm betting that the Canadian real estate will crash, where should I invest my money to minimize losses, and if possible, maximize gains?

For example, I shouldn't invest my money in REITs if I'm betting that the value of real estate will decrease. If a real estate crash does occur, I assume there will be job losses and debt will be accumulated. I assume companies that deal with debt will have more business and therefore profit more. Should I invest my money in these types of companies?

Comment: When you say crash, do you mean prices dropping, massive defaults on mortgages or both? Elaborate on what exactly are you calling a crash here, please.

Comment: US stocks?  Global stocks?  There's not a lot that will profit if there's a major crash in Canada.  Even debt collection/etc. will have some issues as collection rates will drop significantly.  Maybe 'staple' producers (food, beer, etc.)?

Comment: Debt collection companies?

Comment: @JBKing When I say crash, I generally mean a drop in price of real estate. I would assume a massive default would create an oversupply in real estate which would cause real estate prices to crash. I'm not sure if this answers your question.

Comment: @Joe: Your suggestions are all "long" positions, but maybe you could profit more easily by being short something else.

Comment: Shorting in a down market is risky, and you'd have to time the crash right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you believe you can time the crash, then

- “invest” in cash
- keep a good credit rating
- and buy some property just after the crash that cashflows well enough to pay the mortgage for a long time

We all know what comes after a crash… just as we know what comes after the doom, we just don’t know when….

Comment: This assumes you believe the market is going to go back up after the crash.  I'm not sure that the asker believes that.

Comment: Timing the right time to buy in the US market was very tricky, and plenty bought well too early. This is okay if you can afford a risky strategy, but for your average investor seems dangerous.

Comment: @NateEldredge, that way I said "cashflows well", so that there will never be a need to sell.

Comment: @Joe, is is not that risky, if you don't need the money for 20 years and the cashflow works.